# Why is my System.out.println not printing anything in my eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, scala-ide

Using eclipse PDE, I'm running into this very strange error. I start up my plugin by right clicking on the project, Run As -> Eclipse Application.

The target eclipse seems to start up just fine, and in my development eclipse, a console view shows up but it's empty. I can't see any System.out.println's or any exception stacktraces or any of the usual stuff in there.

Answer to my problem below.

Comment: If you enable the option `Preferences > Scala > Logging > Output log in terminal` in the client IDE does it work then?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me (of course this option needs to be enabled in target eclipse instance). So, do not clear workspace in Launch config.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, a different feature I have installed in my eclipse, Scala IDE, is the culprit. For some reason, when it's active, it causes my console to be blank.

To disable it in the target eclipse:

- right click on the project
- Run As -> Run Configurations
- Select the Eclipse Application configuration you've been using.
- Go to the Plugins tab
- Uncheck everything in sight with "Scala" in it.

Console came back after doing this!